# Bad mask /30 for address 10.1.1.3 || Cisco P.T

Tags: cisco, packet

So basically I'm having this issue while trying to configure the serial of 3 routers (router0, router1, router2) on Cisco Packet Tracer

I was able to configure both serials for router0 following this configuration:

Router(config)#interface serial 0/1/1
Router(config-if)#ip address 10.1.1.2 255.255.255.252

I have to clarify that router0 connects its serial 0/1/1 with serial 0/1/1 of router1

When I try to configure router1, I use this configuration:

Router(config)#interface serial 0/1/1
Router(config-if)#ip address 10.1.1.3 255.255.255.252

... but as soon as I hit enter it says "Bad mask /30 for address 10.1.1.3".

And yeah, that's my problem, the same issue happens if I try to configure router2.

This is the issue:
[image: This is the issue]

This is the supposed configuration I have to follow
[image: This is the supposed configuration I have to follow]

Comment: "Usable" addresses in that subnet are `.1` and `.2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

10.1.1.3/30 is the *directed broadcast address* for that subnet and as such, it isn't usable as host address. You can use 10.1.1.1 and 10.1.1.2 from that subnet. If you do need to use 10.1.1.3 you need a shorter mask.

If your devices allow, you should consider using /31 subnets for point-to-point links. Both addresses in /31 are usable for host addressing, wasting none. /30 makes only 50% of the address range usable and is very wasteful.

Also, you don't need to use *any* addressing with physical point-to-point interfaces like serial since you can just route out of the port to reach the far side.

Comment: Thank you so much, it helped me a lot.